# Where does the value returned by the syscalls stored in linux?

Tags: sockets, assembly

```
_start:
    mov ax, 0x167 ;putting syscall number of socket which is 359
    mov bl, 0x2   ;putting 2 as first argument
    mov cl, 0x1   ;putting 1 as second argument
    xor dx, dx    ;putting 0 as third argument
    int x80       ;calling socket(2,1,0)
```

Where will the return value of called function be stored or do I need to specify the register or memory address with some instruction?

Comment: The result is typically returned in `eax`.

Comment: The linked duplicate should address your questions.  If it does not, please comment with any specific questions you might have.

Comment: yes I got my answer dere, the value is returned in eax, thanks!

Comment: Note that the args are the full 32-bit registers, not just the low 8 or 16 bits.

Comment: yes, I did that to avoid null bytes in opcode.